# Integration issues with native code or third-party libraries in flutter any possibility to make that easy

Tags: flutter, swiftui, flutter-dependencies

I recently encountered an issue with my Flutter app while integrating Firebase remote notification functionality. Although the feature worked flawlessly on Android, I faced numerous errors when attempting to run the app on iOS, despite using the exact same codebase.

This problem has led to the app displaying an empty screen on iPhones during the Flutter build process. After investigating the issue, I suspect it may be related to versioning inconsistencies, specifically with regards to the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) token retrieval in iOS.

I am reaching out to seek your guidance and expertise in resolving this challenge. I would greatly appreciate any solutions or recommendations you can provide to help me overcome this problem and ensure proper functioning of the app on iOS devices.

Thank you in advance for your assistance. I eagerly look forward to your response and the opportunity to address this issue promptly.

I want to know the solution that how can i find the version confliction issues overcome easily.
Also want to know how to easily put my flutter stuff on native any easy way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying but the problem is not regarding the code, problem is with the using of packages like firebase package version sometime works on Android but the same code version build make from IOS that's having problem, i face that problem multiple time. I want to just know how can i overcome that issue in future to easily use the version which will compatible with all packages and should works on all platforms smoothly... anything is exist like that?